# Android device battery charging concern

Tags: android, device

i am programming in android and i use an android device to work with my app. i have a concern about the battery of my device. because it will eventually be fully charged after its been plug for long periods of time. lets say more than 8 hours a day. so my questions is.

is it safe for my battery or will it not deteriorate my battery faster if its been plug in too long with the computer?

i don't want to keep unplugging it and plugging it back because i don't want to risk damaging the ports. i don't want to use emulators too because it takes too much time.

any advice and suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: i'm sorry i'm just trying to gather every opinion i could get from experienced developers. i just posted everywhere i could.

Comment: You can use Genymotion (http://www.genymotion.com/). they are emulators, but way faster than the default ones.

Comment: Tools questions are on topic here. In this case, the device is being used as a substitute for an emulator, ie as a tool. But the answer depends on the charge circuit of the particular device.

Comment: Thanks guys, i will try Genymotion emulator because i got a lot of suggestions now to use Genymotion . that could be very handy in creating UIs if it is faster than the defaults one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 best options I can think of:

1. Root your device, and install an app on it allowing you to use
   ADB over WIFI. This is what I have done for years.
2. Get Genymotion as mentioned by many in the comments. They really are a big step above the stock Android emulators. Not only in speed, but they view themselves as "real" devices rather than emulators, so you get a better response to some of the APIs.